# ActsAsTaggableOn: tags not persisting in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using the acts_as_taggable_on (3.4) plugin for tagging with Rails (4.2.4). I've tried adding custom tags both via my seed file and the console and while it appears to add the attributes, I can't then access them.

My model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  acts_as_taggable_on :dietaries, :meals, :cuisines, :sources
end
```

Seed file:

```
tarte = Recipe.create(title: "Caramelized Tomato Tarte Tatin", url: "www.chocolateandzucchini.com", notes: "Lorem ipsum", favorite: false)

tarte.dietary_list.add("vegetarian," "vegan")
tarte.meal_list.add("appetizers", "mains", "dinner")
tarte.cuisine_list.add("French")
tarte.source_list.add("Chocolate and Zucchini")
```

Console steps (after running seed to create the recipe in the seed file above):

```
tarte = Recipe.first
tarte.dietary_list.add("vegetarian," "vegan")
tarte.meal_list.add("appetizers", "mains", "dinner")
tarte.cuisine_list.add("French")
tarte.source_list.add("Chocolate and Zucchini")
```

When I call Recipe.first.dietary_list, it runs a query

```
Recipe Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes"  ORDER BY "recipes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.7ms)SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'dietaries' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 1], ["taggable_type", "Recipe"]]
```

But it returns an empty array:

```
=> []
```

If I call Recipe.first.dietaries, it returns an empty Collection Proxy:

```
Recipe Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes"  ORDER BY "recipes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."context" = $3  [["taggable_id", 1], ["taggable_type", "Recipe"], ["context", "dietaries"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Is there something about using this tool that I'm missing? Alternatively, are there better tagging tools out there?

Comment: did you ever call `tarte.save` in your seed file, or console steps?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by calling .save after entering all tags